# No widgets are showing in widget gallery for Xcode 15 simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, widgetkit, xcode15

No system or custom widgets are showing in the widget gallery when I run app in the Xcode simulator. I just get an empty sheet when swiping up the iOS widget gallery.

I have tried with the template app you get from launching Xcode and choosing "**Create New Project...**". To start the simulator I pick Iphone 15 as my destination and hit `cmd + r`. Opening the widget gallery just shows an empty sheet.

I have tried starting the system apps (maps, photos, ...) once in case that would trigger the system widgets to start showing in the gallery. I have tried creating a custom widget extension with the out of box template but it won't show in the gallery either.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case widget gallery is empty in iPhone simulator but it works with iPad simulator. For example iPad Air (5G) iOS 15.5